# LaTeX compilation error to the journal of Sensors and Actuators A: Physical

Tags: journal-publishing

I've written research paper on Overleaf. The project contains `main.tex` as the main file, `refs.bib` as the bibliography file, 6 `.pdf` files as figures, and 2 graphs I made using PGFPlots. It compiles without any error in Overleaf. I am trying to submit the paper in the journal of **Sensors and Actuators A: Physical**. At the last step, build PDF for approval, the compiling does not work. It gives a very long error message (through the `main.tex` file) the first page of which is attached below. Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong? [image]

Comment: your screenshot doesn't show an error. Better show the complete log-file.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer thanks for the quick reply. It only gives a pdf file which is more than 30 pages. How do I attach it that you may see?

Comment: show the error message from the log as text not just an image of the top of the log showing no errors

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just realized that the PDF file the editorial manager creates contains the same text as if you'd click on the "Logs and output files" then expand the "Raw logs" in Overleaf. `l.159 ...e end of a DE strip, size of $\qtyproduct
{100x50}{\mm}$, was
wrappe...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\mm ->\ERROR`

Comment: don't put errors in comments you need to preserve line ends to make sense of `The control sequence at the end of the top line ` add  as a code block to the question. Ths also means your question is wrong to say it works with no error on overleaf as you clearly get the same error there, please edit the question.  you have used `\mm` without defining it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the `\mm` is defined in the `siunitx` package. As to the errors, there are colored in blue and Overleaf is compiling without problems. The actual problem why the EM doesn't compile is in the figures. Because after removing the figures for a trial, the EM did compile the text.

Comment: @Gagik you have provided no code and an error message that says `\mm` is not defined, I would believe tex when it says commands are not defined. You can not post an error message _from overleaf_ and  then say there are no errors  on overleaf. Do you have a red circle with an error count?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't have red circles. I have eight yellow triangles with exclamation marks in them. Those are underfull and overfull `\hbox` in paragraph. The code is over 400 lines, so I don't know how to provide it.

Comment: but the error message undefined `\mm` above came from overleaf? or do you mean you cut and pasted it from the journal submission?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it came from Overleaf.

Comment: so that is an error, the overleaf run is not error free! you could also make a example that reproduces the error copy your project delete everything except `$\qtyproduct {100x50}{\mm}$, ` then delete every package not used in the example, post it and its error log here in text blocks in the question (not in comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not shown any code or full error but

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

$\qtyproduct {100x50}{\mm}$,

\end{document}
```

Makes the error you show in the log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \qtyproduct 
                            
l.5 $\qtyproduct
                 {100x50}{\mm}$,
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 $\qtyproduct {100x50}{\mm
                             }$,
?
```

So either `siunitx` is not loaded as here, or it is referenced but not installed in which case the first error would be

```
! LaTeX Error: File `siunitx.sty' not found.
```

Followed by the errors above.

Or you are on a old system with `siunitx` version2

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \qtyproduct 
                            
l.5 $\qtyproduct
                 {100x50}{\mm}$,
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\mm ->\ERROR 
             
l.5 $\qtyproduct {100x50}{\mm
                             }$,
?
```

So it seems you are using v2 which has a different syntax here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

$\SI{100x50}{\mm}$,

\end{document}
```

If you had posted the relevant part of the log, it would have been easer to answer

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
File: siunitx-abbreviations.cfg 2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units
                                           ^^^^^^
```

Comment: thank you very much. The journal EM actually got in touch with me: it turns out they had their own problems with the `BibTex` and `siunitx` package.